# Files.size() implementation in Java 7

Tags: java

Is there any implementation difference between `file.length()` and `Files.size()` in Java? Java 7 introduced `Files.size()` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `java.nio.file.Files` class in JDK 7 is a class that provides static methods that operates on files.

The `Files.size(String path)` method returns the file size based from the [`java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html). It's not nothing to do with `File.length()` as this returns you the actual file size that actually has "connected" to.

Comment: According to the docs [Files.size(Path path)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#size(java.nio.file.Path)) _does_ return the "actual file size":
`Returns the size of a file (in bytes). The size may differ from the actual size on the file system due to compression, support for sparse files, or other reasons. `

Answer (score 20):

The main difference is that [`Files.size()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#size%28java.nio.file.Path%29) can handle things that are not "regular files" (as defined by [`Files.isRegularFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#size%28java.nio.file.Path%29)).

This means that depending on which [`FileSystemProviders`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html) you have available, it could be able to get the size of a file in a ZIP file, it could be able to handle files accessed via FTP/SFTP, ...

Plain old [`File.length()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) can not do any of that. It **only** handles "real" files (i.e. those that the underlying OS handles as files as well).

Answer (score 3):

An important difference is that `Files.size()` throws an IOException if something goes wrong, while `File.length()` simply returns 0. I would therefore recommend using `Files.size()` because:

- It's not possible to differentiate between an empty file and an error occurring with `File.length()` because it will return 0 in both cases.
- If an error occurs you won't get any information on the cause of the error with `File.length()`. In contrast, the IOException thrown from `Files.size()` will generally include a message indicating the cause of the failure.

Additionally, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7226714/489522), `Files.size()` can work with any file system provider (e.g. for ZIP or FTP file systems) while `File.length()` only works with the "regular" file system exposed by your operating system.

Conclusion: In general, prefer methods from the newer `Files` class over the legacy `File` class.